# JQuery Datepicker without year issue with minDate and maxDate set

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a JQuery datepicker that allows you to select the date and month. The year is hidden.

All works fine except when I add `minDate` and `maxDate` to the datepicker settings.

The reason why I've set this is so they cannot change years and I also want it to allow leap years. So I set the min and max dates to 2012 (the last leap year) so that they can choose Feb 29th.

When I click in the date text box, it comes up with December 31 selected even though April 23 is the set date. As soon as I remove `minDate` and `maxDate` it selects April 23 when I select the date text box.

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RWvv/) (with `minDate` and `maxDate`)
- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3sQ8/) (without `minDate` and `maxDate`)

Is this a bug or is there something I can do to rectify this?

My code:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    altField: '#date_alt',
    altFormat: 'mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'MM d',
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    yearRange: '-100:+0',
    minDate: new Date(2012, 1-1, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2012, 12-1, 31),
    beforeShow: function(el, obj) {
       obj.dpDiv.addClass('datepicker_hideyear');
    },
    onClose: function(el, obj){
       setTimeout(function() { obj.dpDiv.removeClass('datepicker_hideyear'); }, 1000);
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Setting the `defaultDate` to a 2012 date does the trick but doesn't set the value of the datepicker. It only loads April 23 2012 and the default date.

```
defaultDate: new Date('04/23/2012'),
```

I have to use `setDate` to "select" April 23 2012 and set is as the value but it ends up with exactly the same results.

```
$('#date').datepicker('setDate', new Date('04/23/2012'));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h23dn/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not specify a year when you add the value to your input. Adding an alert into your beforeShow will show that you're actually getting 2014 (`alert($(this).datepicker("getDate"));`. Since this year isn't in your range, it defaults it to the max date possible.

Removing the value from your input and adding the default date will make this work properly:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
```

and in your datepicker initialization add:

```
defaultDate: new Date(2012, 4-1, 23),
```

After a bit more digging, it looks like this is a bug with jQueryUI. If you don't specify a year format in the dateformat string, it will default to the current year no matter what. That's why setdate fails.

Here is a workaround though: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h23dn/6/)

Here's what I added

```
<div style="position:relative; display: inline-block;">
    <input type="text" id="date-placeholder" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; left:0;" />
</div>
```

This is basically creating a placeholder for displaying the information to the user. The "#date" input is set to visibility:hidden and absolutely positioned over the placeholder (to make the datepicker pop up where it should). I didn't set display:none because the datepicker would fail to work, but jquery still considers visibility:hidden to be visible so it still works.

Then in the javascript, I setup a new event:

```
$("#date-placeholder").click(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker("show");
});
```

This just shows the datepicker manually when the user clicks the textbox. Then, in the onclose event of the datepicker:

```
onClose: function (el, obj) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                obj.dpDiv.removeClass('datepicker_hideyear');
            }, 1000);
            var val = $("#date").val();
            val = val.substr(0, val.length - 4);
            $("#date-placeholder").val(val);
        }
```

Simply get the current value of the date field, and remove the last 4 characters (the year) and set the placeholder to that value.

You also have to change the dateFormat string when you initialize. This is so that there is a year for the control to set properly.

```
dateFormat: 'MM d yy',
```

The code could be fixed up, but take a look at the fiddle and you'll see how it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That makes sense. Using `defaultDate` does the trick but doesn't set the value of the datepicker. I have to use `setDate` to do this but it ends up with exactly the same results. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h23dn/3/). Any ideas?

Comment: And here is an example using the `getDate` command. it's like the `defaultDate` isn't updating it... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h23dn/4/)

Comment: @BenSinclair Updated answer with a solution to that too!

Comment: Thanks @Joel! Appreciate your time. It's definitely clunky but I guess that all we can do for now. Did you by any chance when you were doing research see any bug reports for this? If not I'll see if I can find any and maybe submit a bug report if it hasn't been logged :)

Comment: I didn't see any bug reports, but I also didn't see much about using the datepicker without a year. Strange thing is, when you call setDate, getDate does actually return the correct year, it's just the popup calendar that doesn't register it correctly and automatically select it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a value on the input, can you not use the defaultDate property of the datepicker method?

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date('04/23/2012');
    altField: '#date_alt',
    altFormat: 'mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'MM d',
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    yearRange: '-100:+0',
    minDate: new Date(2012, 1-1, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2012, 12-1, 31),
    beforeShow: function(el, obj) {
       obj.dpDiv.addClass('datepicker_hideyear');
    },
    onClose: function(el, obj){
       setTimeout(function() { obj.dpDiv.removeClass('datepicker_hideyear'); }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That makes sense. Using `defaultDate` does the trick but doesn't set the value of the datepicker. I have to use `setDate` to do this but it ends up with exactly the same results. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h23dn/3/). Any ideas?